# Is it possible to colorize a single connected component of a binary image in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've been wondering if you could give me some advise on adding color to a single connected component of a binary image,
here is what i did;
first, in order to use bwlabel function of matlab, i turned my RGB image to binary,
then i wrote a program to ask user which component he/she wants.
now the problem is our TA has asked us to colorize the selected component then show the result.
but i don't know even if it's possible or not, and if it is how to do that..
thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I found a this function on the web: label2rgb

Comment: Any idea how to use it? or does it work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the RGB colour space for this purpose. Since you have not provided any sample data, I'll explain with the `bwlabel` example from MATLAB.

```
BW = logical([1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
              1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
              1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
              1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
              1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
              1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
              1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
              1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]);
L = bwlabel(BW,4);    %Result
imshow(L);
```

[image]

Now L would be:

```
 1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     1     1     0     2     2     0     0
 1     1     1     0     2     2     0     0
 1     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
 1     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
 1     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
 1     1     1     0     0     3     3     0
 1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

Suppose I want to use the colours red, green and blue for components 1,2 and 3 respectively:

```
[m, n] = size(L);
result_image = zeros(m, n, 3);
result_image(:,:,1) = (L==1);
result_image(:,:,2) = (L==2);
result_image(:,:,3) = (L==3);
imshow(result_image);
```

[image]

If you had, say, another connected component 4 (or even more), you could have used something like:

```
result_image(:,:,1) = result_image(:,:,1) + (L==4)*1;
result_image(:,:,2) = result_image(:,:,2) + (L==4)*0.5;
result_image(:,:,3) = result_image(:,:,3) + (L==4)*0;
```

For different colours, simply play around with the multiplied values (1, 0.5 and 0 here).

Comment: @RmanEdv: Happy to help. :) Do accept the answer if you're satisfied with it.